# What is the access-level of Solidity's implicit getters?

Tags: solidity

I have a "real" contract and an interface contract.

In the interface contract, I want only to expose the 'getter' functions of the "real" contract.

Those functions are implicitly generated by the Solidity compiler (solc).

The options, I suppose, are:

1. `external constant`
2. `public constant`
3. `external view`
4. `public view`

But no matter how I try it, the binary of my "real" contract comes out with no contents.

The only way I am able to work-around it is by explicitly implementing the 'getter' functions (in the "real" contract).

Since those functions can also be generated implicitly, I was hoping to avoid it, so I would like to know if by any chance I'm doing anything wrong in the way that I declare these functions in the interface contract.

Here is the interface contract ('ITest.sol'):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ITest {
    function x() external constant returns (uint256);
}
```

And here is the "real" contract ('Test.sol'):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import './ITest.sol';

contract Test is ITest {
    uint256 public x;

    function Test(uint256 _x) public {
        x  = _x;
    }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: "... the binary of my 'real' contract comes out with no contents." Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @smarx: An empty file. There's a description of a similar problem in [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11802/16043).

Comment: Can you share the actual contract(s) you're compiling?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just put `uint256 public x` in `ITest`?

Comment: Well, namely coding conventions. In most languages an interface consists of functions only, no variables. In any case, I'm pretty sure I have tried that approach too, and got the same results. Of course, one could argue that an interface is not needed here altogether, but I'm trying to stick to the general layout of my contracts, in which, for each "real" contract there's a corresponding interface contract, and any two "real" contracts "communicate" with each other only via interface contracts.

Comment: In my testing, it does work to include the public variable in the "interface" contract." (Note that you can use the `interface` keyword if you want to declare an actual interface.) I do like the idea of having public interfaces separate from the implementation, but I'm unable to come up with a way to get Solidity to accept that a public state variable implements the getter function declared.

Comment: @smarx: Thank you. That was my problem too (maybe placing the variables in the interface did work, I can't remember by now). How can I use `interface`? Does it come instead of `contract` or in addition to `contract`?

Comment: Instead. https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#interfaces, but note that interfaces *can't* declare state variables.

Comment: @smarx: Yes, I found that in the docs already, thank you. I don't want any of my interfaces to include state variables (as they normally don't in any other language).