# solc command is generating empty .bin files

Tags: solc, compiler, truffle-compile

Firstly, this is **not** an inheritance problem like in [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11802/solc-returns-empty-bin-for-contracts-with-constructor-and-inheritance)

I have the following two files ( ManagedWallet.sol & ManagedWalletLookup.sol )

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ManagedWalletLookup { 
    address private _owner;

    mapping(address => address) public _managedWallets;

    constructor () internal {
        _owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier isOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == _owner);
        _;
    }

    function updateManagedWallets(address wallet, address owner) public 
        isOwner {
        _managedWallets[owner] = wallet;
    }

}
```

and...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ManagedWallet {
    address private _owner;
    address private _manager;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor (address owner) internal {
        _owner = owner;
        _manager = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier isOwnerOrManager() {
        require(msg.sender == _owner || msg.sender == _manager);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public isOwnerOrManager {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
}
```

When I type

```
 solc --version
```

into the terminal it prints

```
Version: 0.4.24+commit
```

so the solc is the right version. However, anytime I enter the command

```
solc ManagedWallet.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o ./
```

or

```
solc ManagedWalletLookup.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o ./
```

It returns empty .bin files

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: As far as I remember, if you don't specify `--output-dir`, then solc prints the output in the terminal instead of saving it into a file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it just prints "bin: " and nothing following it